# ECS Error: "The closest matching container-instance is missing an attribute required by your task"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have created a ECS Service, which is not able to run any tasks in the EC2 containers. I keep getting this message under the "Events" tab for Service.

```
service QA-SVC was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching container-instance f84f8418-2b63-4d02-ac5f-2ee3860d4fac is missing an attribute required by your task.
```

I have read almost all the question thread in SO, but I am not able to figure out the cause of this error. The error message does not clearly explain the specific attribute that is missing (or mismatching). I do not know what is in EC2 that I need to configure for the tasks to run on it.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to find out which attributes are missing is using [`ecs-cli check-attributes`](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli#checking-for-missing-attributes-and-debugging-reason-attribute-errors).

Comment: I tried this and got `None` for missing attributes for the exact task and cluster I am trying to run. However, I still get same error message and the service is unable to run the task. Any other pointers?

Comment: I had tried various ways and finally this command helped me to get the list of missing attributes. If this command returns `None` then please double check the option values you are passing with this command and make sure they are correct. Its hard to think of a reason why it returns `None` while you are still getting missing attributes error. I have moved on from that project and not using AWS currently so can't say much.

Comment: Thanks @Alpesh . It turns out the error I was facing was due to another setting of `arch` in my task definition. It was set to `ARM` whereas I had moved to using `x86` instance. The `ecs-cli check-attributes` does not highlight these differences. In my opinion the AWS error message should be improved.

Comment: I ran into same issue as `Sarang`, the `ecs-cli` showed `None` but the `"runtimePlatform"` in task configuration was incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

This error is thrown because, as it says, your instance `is missing an attribute required by your task`.

> Some task definition parameters require a specific Docker remote API
>   version to be installed on the container instance. Others, such as the
>   logging driver options, require the container instances to register
>   those log drivers with the ECS_AVAILABLE_LOGGING_DRIVERS agent
>   configuration variable. If your task definition contains a parameter
>   that requires a specific container instance attribute, and you do not
>   have any available container instances that can satisfy this
>   requirement, the task cannot be placed. [source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-event-messages.html#service-event-messages-1)

How and what attributes you need to configure depends on your task definition requirements. Some require you to update container agent configuration that can be found under `/etc/ecs/ecs.config` if you have used to ECS optimized AMI.

You will need to go through these links ([task definition parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html) and [container agent configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html)) to find out how to exactly configure your instances based on your task definition requirements.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue, and ran this command: `ecs-cli check-attributes --container-instances <INSTANCE_ID> --task-def <TASK_DEF_ARN> --cluster <CLUSTER_NAME> --region us-east-1`

This command was recommended in many places, but my output was just:

```
Container Instance  Missing Attributes
ClusterName None
```

It turns out that in my task definition JSON, the `runtimePlatform`.`cpuArchitecture` was set to `ARM64` instead of `X86_64`. Updating this then fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Task Definition was requiring a subnet that wasn't use by any of the cluster EC2 instances.