# How to run ECS task on EC2 with awsvpc?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to run a service on an ECS cluster, using the EC2 launch type.

I've configured a task definition, and specifying the `awsvpc` network type.
Then, I've created a cluster, and then I've followed [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html) in order to add an EC2 instance to the cluster.

The instance is joined to the cluster, but when I try to run a service with the above task definition, I get:

```
service my-svc was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. 
The closest matching container-instance xxx is missing an attribute required by your task
```

However, if I do the same thing, but this time, instead of manually creating the container instance,  when I create the cluster I choose to create the container instance using the built-in wizard, it does work.

So I understand that there's something in how I configure my container instance (i.e. the Linux EC2) is missing.

I have seen  the thread: [ECS Error: "The closest matching container-instance is missing an attribute required by your task"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56290746/ecs-error-the-closest-matching-container-instance-is-missing-an-attribute-requ), but it didn't help me:

I did check with the `ecs-cli` for missing attributes, but got None.

Can someone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ECS Error: "The closest matching container-instance is missing an attribute required by your task"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56290746/ecs-error-the-closest-matching-container-instance-is-missing-an-attribute-requ)

Comment: I saw this one, no, it doesn't